# JQuery - Resize response object dynamically after loading the content

Tags: jquery, size, response

I am using the jquery method `.html()` to get external content in form of another page (same domain). What I receive is an object within a specific div. So far, so good.
My problem is that this object is way too small (with srcollbars - like a small iframe). I could use a style tag within the object, but this would be static. What I want is a dynamic solution. My current try looks like the following:

```
<div id="siteloader"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $("#siteloader").html('<object id="myobject" style="width:100%; height:100%;" data="http://localhost/">').promise().done(function(){
        $("#siteloader").height($("#myobject")[0].scrollHeight);
});

</script>
```

Sadly it doesn't work. What did I do wrong? :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to get rid of the scrollbar? or make the object fit in the window?

Comment: I want to make it fit into the window.

Comment: Why don't you use `iframe` tag? it's better than `object` tag

Comment: Because as far as I know iframes are no longer supported in html5

Comment: No, [HTML elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames) `iframe` is **allowed** in HTML 5.
You can use it!

Comment: Just heard they were not part of HTML 5, not that performant and JQuery was better. But after all I will use iframes then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you are still insisted on using `object` tags, use:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
        <body>
        </body>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
          <script>
          $(document.body).html('<object id="myobject" style="width:100%; height:100%;" data="http://localhost/">');
          </script>
</html>
```

& to fit your object to the window use CSS:

```
body{
margin:0px;
};
```